# problema al obtener el nombre de clase

Tags: php, namespace

En mi código tengo un metodo que usa get_class para obtener el nombre de la clase. Por ejemplo si tenía la clase User, guardaba ese nombre de clase en una variable.

Hace poco comencé a usar los namespace con psr-4, pero ahora esa función get_class me devuelve el namespace de la clase. O sea de esa clase User me devuelve App\Models\User

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que funcione como antes sin quitar los namespace?

Este es el método, solo la parte del get_class($this) es la que funciona como no quiero:

```
public function parseClassNameToTable(){

    $className = preg_replace('/(?<=\w)(\p{Lu})/u', '_$1', get_class($this));
    $className = mb_strtolower($className);

    return $className . 's';
}
```

Comment: Hola, sería genial que compartiera lo que llevas hecho y que te da problemas , muestralo para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: listo he agregado el metodo, antes de usar psr-4 funcionaba bien :/

Comment: Prueba cualquiera de estas, te las pondré en orden de rendimiento, la más rápida es la 1ª, la más lenta es la 3ª.  **1.** `substr(strrchr(get_class($this), "\\"), 1);`  **2.** `(new \ReflectionClass($this))->getShortName();` y **3.** `basename(str_replace('\\', '/', get_class($this)));` Prueba y comenta el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Desde PHP 5.4 La constante **CLASS** te devuelve el FQNS (Fully Qualified Namespace) de la clase. Podrías hacer:

```
    $FQNS_array = explode('\\', __CLASS__);
    $className  = array_pop($FQNS_array);
```